# What's the meaning of "this year agone"?

Tags: word-meaning

> "Drat thee" yelled the witch-bodies, "thou'st spoiled our spells **this**
>   **year agone**!"

This is from a English fairly tale "The Buried Moon". I knew that "agone" is archaic form of ago, but does "this year ago" make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it means "for a year now". The meaning can be akin to that of "since".

> You have spoiled our spells for a year now.

Compare Shakespeare *Twelfth Night* (V. i.)

> Oh, he's drunk, Sir Toby, an hour agone.

... inebriated *since an hour ago*, or "this past hour", or "for an hour now".

Answer (score 0):

After reading a [source](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/eng/meft/meft24.htm) of the question I would update the sentence to

> "Damn you" yelled the devils, "you have spoiled the spells we cast a
>   year ago!"

The most difficult part is "witch-bodies" and in the text [**Bogles**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogle) is mentioned, and the text also uses various other terms which generally mean supernatural entities, perhaps conjured up by the mind. So I simplified that to "devils".

Comment: I would like to know the reason for a down vote, please share it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can "this year ago" mean "a year ago"?

Comment: "this year agone" and "this year ago" are not said today, which is why I rephrased it as "a year ago".